# jQuery appendTo effecting multiple elements

Tags: jquery, append

I'm using a simple `appendTo` to move some `<figcaption>` tags inside some `<a href>`. I can do this easy enough using:

```
$('.company-panel figcaption').appendTo('.company-panel a');
```

But I have multiple `<div class="company-panel">` on the page and it's moving all `<figcaption>` rather than the ones relative to the panel.

```js
$('.company-panel figcaption').appendTo('.company-panel a');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="company-panel">
  <a href="#">link - move figcaption below here</a>
  <figcaption>Caption 1</figcaption>
</div>

<div class="company-panel">
  <a href="#">link - move figcaption below here</a>
  <figcaption>Caption 2</figcaption>
</div>

<div class="company-panel">
  <a href="#">link - move figcaption below here</a>
  <figcaption>Caption 3</figcaption>
</div>
```

This is what I want outputted:

```
<div class="company-panel">
  <a href="#">link <figcaption>Caption 1</figcaption></a>
</div>

<div class="company-panel">
  <a href="#">link <figcaption>Caption 2</figcaption></a>
</div>

<div class="company-panel">
  <a href="#">link <figcaption>Caption 3</figcaption></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code:

```
$('.company-panel').map((i,el)=>{
  let fig = $(el).children('figcaption').text();
  $(el).children('a').html(`<figcaption>${fig}</figcaption>`);
  $(el).children('figcaption').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has different traversing methodes for this one the [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) methode is the right

```
$('.company-panel figcaption').appendTo($(this).siblings('a'));
```